# How to detect player death events fabricMC

Tags: java, minecraft-fabric

I need to listen to a PlayerDeathEvent, but I cannot find any way of listening to it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you could post your code and what is not working, we could possibly help you

Comment: well i dont know where to start, any pointer would be useful

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [Mixin](https://fabricmc.net/wiki/tutorial:mixin_introduction).

It effectively inserts code at a function, class, or changes variables.
In your instance, register a mixin using a PlayerEntity class, then use the onDeath function and insert into it.
I'll provide the injection annotation, but this is something you'll want to learn when using fabric.

```java
@Inject(method="onDeath", at=@At("TAIL"))
```

The above mixin will insert the function you put after right before returning.

I'd also really recommend reading the fabric tutorials, it's helped me through quite a bit.